# Do Service Workers throw file not found errors when off line?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My service worker is set up and working on-line.  It appears to be working off line, but then it throws an error.  Says it can't find the service-worker.js file.

Is this because it's looking for the file off-line and can't find it?  Is there a way of not having this error?
[Screen grab of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfJtM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your service worker is trying to download a copy of the service worker script file, even though it's offline. Since service workers can contain arbitrary javascript code, they can try to download and throw any errors that they want - it appears yours tries to download itself and throws an error. The only way to get rid of the error will be to look into the code and prevent it from being thrown.